# How to set an exact background position based on element's position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to achieve: using the same image, set an elements `background-position` with jQuery, so they overlaps closest parents `background-image`. I somehow figured, that `$element.property().left` needs to be multiplied by something close to `2` (still don't really understand why it's so), but I cannot see any math pattern in it.

If anybody could tell me what exactly comes into an equation, it'd be great help. I imagine there is `padding` and `margin` of an element and all the elements up the DOM tree involved, but after lot of combinations I still cannot get there.

It might seem that the best way to get desired effect is just to set `background: transparent;`, but *it is not the case*; I need it for further usage of `filter` CSS property on the element's background image.

There are inline styles in HTML added for testing; also, I created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a37z23hh/).

```js
$.fn.filteredImg= function() {
    
    var $this = $(this)

    $this.each(function(index, card) {
        var $card   = $(card);
        var img     = $card.data("img");
        var $parent = $card.parentsUntil("[data-img='" + img + "']").last().parent();
        var $effect = $card.children(".filtered-effect");
        var pos     = $card.position();
        $parent.css({ 
            backgroundImage: "url(" + img + ")",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
        });
        $effect.css({
            backgroundImage: "url(" + img + ")",
            backgroundPosition: -2 * Math.ceil(pos.left) + "px " + -Math.round(pos.top) + "px"
        });
    })
    

}   

$(".card-filtered-img").filteredImg();
```

```css
.card-filtered-img {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-left: 77px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  position: relative; 
}
  .card-filtered-img > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
  }
  .card-filtered-img .filtered-effect {
    z-index: 99; 
  }
  .card-filtered-img .card-content {
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.35);
    z-index: 100; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-img="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg">
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
      <div class="row" style="padding:30px">
          <div class="col">
              <div class="card-filtered-img" data-img="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg">
                  <div class="filtered-effect"></div>
                  <div class="card-content"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="card-filtered-img" data-img="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg">
                  <div class="filtered-effect"></div>
                  <div class="card-content"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why using images ? Why don't you use a `transparent` background and playing with `opacity` ?

Comment: Because, for example, you cannot use `filter: blur(5px)` with transparent background and opacity.

Comment: You can also try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QvSng/192/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution base on `offset` instead of `position` (and I simplified the code):

```js
$.fn.filteredImg= function() {
    
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.each(function(index, card) {
        var $card   = $(card);
        var $effect = $card.children(".filtered-effect");
        var $parent = $(card).parents(".parent").first();
        var img     = $parent.data("img");
        var cardPos = $card.offset();
        $parent.css({ 
            backgroundImage: "url(" + img + ")",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
        });
        $effect.css({
            backgroundImage: "url(" + img + ")",
            backgroundPosition: -cardPos.left + "px " + -cardPos.top + "px"
        });
    })
    

}   

$(".card-filtered-img").filteredImg();
```

```css
.card-filtered-img {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-left: 77px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  position: relative; 
}
  .card-filtered-img > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; 
  }
  .card-filtered-img .filtered-effect {
    z-index: 99; 
  }
  .card-filtered-img .card-content {
    background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.35);
    z-index: 100; 
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" data-img="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-filtered-img">
              <div class="filtered-effect"></div>
              <div class="card-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-filtered-img">
              <div class="filtered-effect"></div>
              <div class="card-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And I was calculating something close to the Moon's radius.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since/If you use the full viewport, you can use viewport units to position and size the inner *card*'s and drop the script all together.

This also scales when you resize and will give you a performance boost since you don't need a script to watch for resize and redraw.

*Note, for this demo I ran this without `bootstrap`, as I didn't want to add compensations for its media query's etc.*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a37z23hh/2/)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.outer {
  height: 1080px;
  width: 100vw;
}
.card-acrylic {
  top: 20px;
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-position: left -10vw top -20px;
}
.card-acrylic + .card-acrylic {
  top: 40px;
  background-position: left -10vw top -540px;
}

.card-acrylic > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card-acrylic .acrylic-effect {
  z-index: 99;
}

.card-acrylic .card-content {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.35);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg)">

  <div class="card-acrylic" style="background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg)">
    <div class="acrylic-effect"></div>
    <div class="card-content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-acrylic" style="background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-wallpaper2.jpg)">
    <div class="acrylic-effect"></div>
    <div class="card-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```